# Auto increment a non-primary key (SQL Server 2014) in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, increment

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Helper.openConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Helper.cn;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Characters values(@Name, 'Novice', 1, 40, 10, 0, @STR, @AGI, @VIT, @DEX, @LUK, @INT, 1, 1)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STR", txtStr.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AGI", txtAgi.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VIT", txtVit.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEX", txtDex.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LUK", txtLuk.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INT", txtInt.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Helper.cn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Character successfully created!");
        this.Close();
}
```

Written above is my code for a simple character creation screen for my project in C#. I have a problem of doing an auto increment of the `CharacterSlot` column, which is a non-primary key since in the picture below, `CharacterID` is my primary key.

I also chose `CharacterID` as primary since we can have multiple characters per account. Below are images from my SQL Server database.

[image: Characters Table]

[image: Users Table]

EDIT: Per character slot is a clickable picture box that changes the values of the stats written on the character selection screen, the thing is, if the `CharacterSlot` is always 1, it will just show Helios' stats and not the other characters that I will create (up to 3).

[image: Character Creation and Character Selection]

How do I work around this?

Comment: What would be the purpose? If you were to sort by it, it would provide you with the same order as CharacterID.

Comment: Why do you need multiple auto increment fields in the same table?  Perhaps sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: @ESG I will use it to be able to shuffle from character to character, I will post a screenshot for update.

Comment: @sgeddes Will update my question.

Comment: By the way, it is a really good idea to always list your column names. `insert into Characters (column1, column2, etc.) values (...)`. This will protect you from changes to your tables.

Comment: Do you really want autoincrement, or do you want "autoincrement starting at 1 per user"? I ask because that's a different question entirely.

Comment: @JonathanAllen Ohh, I might try listing the columns on my future projects. About your question, I want it to auto increment per character created so that they will have different CharacterSlot and I can use the Picture Boxes in the character selection to show the data of the character with the corresponding Character Slot (first one is 1, second one is 2, so on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the Sequence object is for.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO

CREATE TABLE Test.TestTable
     (CounterColumn int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(25) NOT NULL) ; 
GO

INSERT Test.TestTable (CounterColumn,Name)
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1, 'Syed') ;
GO

SELECT * FROM Test.TestTable; 
GO
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx

You can also use `NEXT VALUE FOR` in the `DEFAULT` constraint on a column.

Comment: Oh, can I use sequence as CommandText in C#? I'm fairly new to C# so any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So if you want the recount to restart per use, you need to do this. Notice how the command text declares its own parameter for the count that it wants to look up.

```
CREATE Database Test1
GO
Use Test1
GO
CREATE TABLE TestTable
     (CounterColumn int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    SlotNumber INT NOT nULL,
    UserId INT NOT NULL

    )
GO


---- SQL Command Parameters----

Declare @Name nvarchar(25) = 'Tom';
Declare @UserId INT = 1;


----------------------- SQL Command Text------------
Declare @SlotNumber INT;
SELECT @SlotNumber = IsNull(Max(SlotNumber), 0) + 1 FROM TestTable WHERE UserId=@UserId;
INSERT INTO TestTable (Name, SlotNumber, UserId) VALUES (@Name, @SlotNumber, @UserId);

--------Check results -----------

SELECT * FROM TestTable
```